# How to run a sql query inside a WLST script

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic, wlst

As it is possible to access a specific weblogic jdbc datasource in wlst, how can we run a sql query on this datasource ?

Here is how i retreive the specific datasource :

```
# Load the properties file with all necessary values
loadProperties('domain.properties')
# Go online
connect(adminusername, adminpassword,'t3://' + adminurl)
serverRuntime()
dsMBeans = cmo.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
oamDS = 'oamDS'
for ds in dsMBeans:
    if (ds.getName() == oamDS):
              #how to do something like this : ds.query('Select * from AM_REPLICATION_SETTINGS') ?
disconnect()
exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this WLST command

loadDB('12C', 'myDataSource', 'select name from emp')